# Python Text Game: If Elif Statement Doesn't Return Context-Dependent Info (e.g., Room Description without Item Description)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I’ve created a simple, Python text game that permits a Player to ‘move’ from room to room, and ‘take’ items from each room, adding them to the Player Inventory.

I’m trying to add a basic enhancement, though, that returns a context-dependent Room Description to the Player, depending upon whether they’ve already taken a Room’s Item.

For example, when a Player enters Room 2 the first time, they’ll receive a Room Description WITH Item Description.

If they ‘take’ the Room 2 Item, leave the Room, and later return, the Player will receive a Room Description WITHOUT Item Description (because the Room Item is already in their Inventory).

This seems like it should be an extremely simple If-Elif-Else statement, but, using the code below, when the Player returns to a Room, after having taken that Room’s Item, I get a KeyError, which notes the Room’s name (e.g., ‘room 2’).

When I’ve tried variations of the code, the other result I’ve received is the Room Description WITHOUT Item Description, even on first entry (i.e., before the Room Item has been ‘taken’, the WITHOUT Item Description is returned).

I’m stumped as to what I need to correct in the code; any help would be very much appreciated!

---

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, current_room):
        self.current_room

inventory = []

Player.current_room = 'room 1'
inventory.append('Key')
new_game = True

def move_player(selected_action):

    # Splits Player input String to determine selected Direction of movement
    split_action = selected_action.split(' ', 1)
    direction = split_action[1]

    # Determines viability of selected Player direction through reference to >> rooms << Dictionary
    if direction in rooms[Player.current_room]:
        Player.current_room = rooms[Player.current_room][direction]

        # current_room_item = room_items[Player.current_room] # Tried to assign Current Room Item to Variable for use in If Statement below

        # THIS IF ELSE DOESN'T WORK FOR SOME REASON, RETURNS KeyError
        # if current_room_item in inventory: # Tried this variation using the variable above, didn't work (KeyError)
        print(room_items[Player.current_room])
        if room_items[Player.current_room] in inventory: # Checks to see if the Item for the Current Room is in Player Inventory
            print(roomONLY_desc[Player.current_room]) # If Room Item IS in Inventory, print Room Only Description
        else:
            print(roomITEM_desc[Player.current_room]) # If Room Item is NOT in Inventory, prints Room Description WITH Item
    else:
        print('There\'s nothing in that direction.')

    # Assigns newly-entered Room to current_room Property of Player Class
    return Player.current_room

def take_item(selected_action):
    # Splits Player input String to determine Item the Player wishes to add to Inventory
    split_action = selected_action.split(' ', 1)
    selected_item = split_action[1]
    print(selected_item)
    print(selected_item == room_items[Player.current_room])

    # Determines if Player-identified Item is a valid Game Item, and if it is located in the Current Room
    if selected_item == room_items[Player.current_room]:
        inventory.append(room_items[Player.current_room])
        print(
            f'''
        You've added the {room_items[Player.current_room]} to your Inventory!

        Your inventory contains: {inventory}

                \u2B50   \u2B50   \u2B50
            '''
        )
        room_items.pop(Player.current_room)
    else:
        print("No such item is available to pick up.")

def main():

    while new_game:

        print(f'In Room: {Player.current_room}')
        selected_action = input('Action: ')
        action = selected_action.split()

        if action[0] == 'move':
            move_player(selected_action)
        elif action[0] == 'take':
            take_item(selected_action)
        elif action[0] == 'exit':
            print('Exit')
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid')

rooms = {
    'room 1': {'E': 'room 2'},
    'room 2': {'E': 'room 3', 'W': 'room 1'},
    'room 3': {'W': 'room 2'}
}

room_items = {
    'room 1': 'item 1',
    'room 2': 'item 2',
    'room 3': 'item 3'}

roomITEM_desc = {
    'room 1': 'room 1 ITEM: item 1',
    'room 2': 'room 2 ITEM: item 2',
    'room 3': 'room 3 ITEM: item 3'
}

roomONLY_desc = {
    'room 1': '1 withOUT item',
    'room 2': '2 withOUT item',
    'room 3': '3 withOUT item'
}

main()
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I didn't read your code in detail, but in the `take_item` function you pop the item entry from room_items, so no wonder you get a key error later; better set an `item_taken` dict with boolean values, and test this dict to determine which room description to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by popping the key from `room_items`.  The line is: `room_items.pop(Player.current_room)` because rather than simply removing the item from that key in the dictionary, you are removing the entire key altogether.  That's why you are getting a KeyError, because the 'Key' no longer exists as you popped it after taking the item from the room.  Then once you try to re-enter the room, you are looking for that key, and it no longer exists.

You can fix this issue by not popping the item anymore and doing something such as setting it to a different value, like `room_items[Player.current_room] = ""`. That line will allow you to keep the key in your dictionary, but no longer have the 'item 2' associated with it. This will mean you will have to change the way you check that the item is no longer in the room however.  I would suggest maybe making a dictionary of rooms associated with a list of items instead of just a string, and remove the item from the list as opposed to popping the entire room from `room_items`.

It could look something like this:

```
room_items = {
   'room 1': ['item 1'],
   'room 2': ['item 2', 'item 4'],
   'room 3': ['item 3']
}
```

This way you can have multiple items in a single room, and verify whether or not the item is actually in that room.

```
if 'item 2' in room_items['room 2']:
   # The item is in the room
else:
   # The item is not in the room
```

and then to remove the item from that list:
`room_items['room 2'].remove('item 2')`

Comment: Thank you! I'll made that change, and I did need to revise my check on Items taken, but it solved the issue, really appreciate the help